# Find mapping between two lists of strings

Tags: algorithms, text-mining, natural-language

I have two lists named `A` and `B` both containing the names of ingredients from some number of recipes. List `A` contains unique and standard ingredients like the following:

```
cheese
chicken
chicken breast
ham
stock
beef chuck and blade
...
```

while list `B` contains ingredients in a non-consistent and non-unique way, like:

```
low-fat cheese
goat cheese
chicken breast halves
bone-in chicken breast
less sodium ham
less sodium smoked fully cooked ham
low sodium chicken stock
...
```

Now, for each ingredient in list `B`, I want to find its most similar counterpart in list `A`. A simple search of ingredients of list `A` in list `B` won't work because:

1. Some ingredients in list `B` have more than one matching in list `A`
2. There might be misspelling in list `B`
3. There are semantically same but differently written ingredients in list `B`, such as "coconut cream" and "cream of coconut".

What is the best method to find such mapping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) is a common metric for measuring the dissimilarity between two strings, using the minimal number of insertions, deletions, or permutations necessary to align them. For instance, cart differs from "cat", "care", and "chart" by only 1. This is useful for correcting spelling, but not much more.

Since the first list serves as a gold standard, you can reject modifiers in the second list that have no alignment. For instance, the word "low" may not appear in the first list, presumably a superfluous modifier.

You can generalize levenshtein distance to include whole words as part of a dictionary. So for instance, I can have a "dictionary" which includes letters of "cheese" "chicken" "chicken breast" "ham", and the levenshtein distance from "low-fat cheese" and "cheese" would be 1, and from "bone-in chicken breast" and "chicken breast" is 1 whereas "chicken" would have a distance of 2 because you have to delete "bone-in" and "breast".